# How to get the prompt of a spinner via method?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to validate an EditText field in my android app. The field is spinner. The prompt is defined in the .xml. If I output it in the console, it appears correctly. However, when part of a Toast's structure, within a method, the address of the spinner is printed rather than the prompt:
Spinner validation in a validating class:

```
public static boolean spinnerValidated(Spinner spinner) {
    return  spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==(0);

}
```

It's invocation in the main class:

```
private void validateSpinner(Spinner spinner) {
    if (Utility.spinnerValidated(spinner)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Invalid data for field " + spinner.getPrompt().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Call of the method:

```
validateSpinner(spinner);
```

Spinner xml:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@style/spinner"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rectangle"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:prompt="@string/subcategory"/>
```

And the Style:

```
 <style name="spinner">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Show you xml. Your code seems fine.

Comment: I've just added it, thanks!

Comment: This code should work. I can't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: The only sugestion I can make is change the context in `Toast` from `getApplicationContext()` to `YourActivty.this`.

Comment: No idea why, but on this way it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Toast` doesn't need the global application context. The scope of this `Toast` is only for the Activity.

Change your context from `getApplicationContext()` to `YourActivty.this`.